# Can I upgrade my Android Studio version from 2.3.3 to 3.0 in windows?

Tags: android, windows, updates

I can't update my Android Studio app from 2.3.3 to 3.0... I am not getting any update notifications either! Can't I update this? 
If I can't, how should I get the newer features of Android studio 3?

NB: I am using windows 10

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Comment: No there is no need to update it now. Its under preview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

android studio 3.0 stable version haven't released yet. you will get when it will release. u can also get 3.0 beta version. it may have some bug. [click here to get 3.0 beta 2](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio 3.0 is out now, to get it you have to click on Help>Check for Updates. Once it finishes checking for updates, a window will appear with the Download option.

Or if you prefer, you can get right from here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?utm_source=android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can update Android studio to 3.0, as Android studio 3.0 update is targetting only for 64bit OS version. After upgrading you must open and clean the project and then you can directly run on your Android device.

Comment: Got any references?

Answer (score 1):

Stable version is Released Now.

Follow These Steps...

In Android Studio,

1)select File > Settings (or Android Studio > Preference on Mac).

2)In the left pane, select Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates.

3)Be sure that Automatically check for updates is checked, and then select a channel from the drop-down list.

4)Click OK.

5)Download it Now..

Ref: [Click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html)